# fix() error with XQuartz cannot be solved

Tags: r

I was following this extremely easy example from ISLR book,

[image]

I used fix() for the first time (I usually just used head()), and I got the first error... I followed the error and went to xquartz.macosforge.org and installed it, and then I got the second error "X11 dataentry cannot be loaded"

I thought fix() was part of base... why I am I getting two different errors? Why is XQuartz needed for an R base function?

I restarted r studio and now I get:
[image]

Comment: Because "base R" and "X11" are not mutually exclusive. R for macOS is (usually by default) compiled with X11 support. What happens if you restart RStudio and try it again? What version of R do you have? How did you install it? Do you have command line tools for macos installed? What's your `sessionInfo()`.  Did you try `utils::edit.data.frame()`? (please answer those _in question_ and in _code blocks_ … it would also be better to copy the console text output and put that in a _code block_ vs make us load images).

Answer (score 0):

When you run `fix()`, it writes the object to a file and runs `edit()` on it.  `edit()` looks at `getOption("editor")` to find out how to edit the file.

Whatever editor it is finding requires X11.  You not only need to install XQuartz, you need to make sure that the environment variable `"DISPLAY"` is set properly so X11 knows where to open the window.  Use `Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")` to see how yours is set.

Mine is set to `"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.wcbe5TKA8E/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"`.  If you have just installed XQuartz, you may need to reboot, or at least re-open the terminal, to have this set properly.